WebSocket connection fails with error 'Connection closed without response' on Heroku deploymen
This is my Heroku log I am getting :

2024-08-12T09:53:56.777286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=spoken-8892a1fe4a30.herokuapp.com request_id=2bb710b5-1f31-4ebd-9d4d-0d82a8dd9340 fwd="103.61.241.16" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Here is the relevant part of the code of backend :
@SubscribeMessage('getActiveUsers')
handleGetActiveUsers(client: Socket, filterDto: FilterDto) {
    try {
        this.logger.log(`Received getActiveUsers request from client: ${client.id}`);

        // Ensure filterDto is not null or undefined
        if (!filterDto) {
            this.logger.warn('filterDto is null or undefined');
            filterDto = {}; 
        }

        const activeUsersArray = Array.from(this.activeUsers.values());
        const filteredUsers = this.homeService.filterUsers(activeUsersArray, filterDto);
        client.emit('activeUsers', filteredUsers);
    } catch (error) {
        this.logger.error('Error fetching active users', error.stack);
    }
}

When I try the getActiveUsers event I get disconnected.
What I Tried:
I tried restarting all dynos.
Adjusted pingTimeout and pingInterval.
Checked Heroku logs; consistent H13 errors during WebSocket disconnections.
Configured SSL in Heroku.
Expected:
Stable WebSocket connection without unexpected disconnections.
